# Would Codeigniter 2 be a good choice for my case - explained below?

Tags: jquery-mobile, codeigniter-2, php

Have spent a week trying to wrap my head around Yii framework, but while I do get a sense of it's elegance, I am finding the learning curve rather steep, compared to the 2 days I spent on Codeigniter. My background is of Unix systems programming (communication stacks), with no MVC exposure, and know only basic PHP (find it fairly simple & straight-forward).

I've considered the no-framework approach, but find it even more daunting given that, I've almost no web-development experience. A framework, at minimum would give guidance in terms of architecture & design.

I might be shooting myself in the foot, but with a tight deadline on ramp-up, and delivering a somewhat complex web-application, I need to get productive real fast.

So wondering if community can guide me, if Codeigniter 2.x, would be good choice for me, given the following requirements --

1. Easy to learn and able to deliver quickly, something that is functional. Thus needs to have extensive, easy-to-use documents, tutorials (beyond simple-blogs) and a very active community.
2. Framework needs to make it easy to integrate features like -

   - User registration with captcha
   - User verification using random verification key sent via mobile phone
   - Send Email, short-message to mobile phone
   - Integrate with Payment Gateway
   - Have significant no. (close to a hundred) possible CRUD operations
   - Doesn't get in the way (if not making it easy) to work with AJAX, for things like timeline presentation - including audio-snippets, photographs, video-snippets
   - Doesn't get in the way (if not making it easy) for the web application to be made accessible on mobile devices s.a. smartphones
3. Has reasonable performance. Need not be the fastest, but performance is a concern, although secondary.

Of course, I do not need all the features on day-1, and willing to invest some time in reading/learning about the framework, but wouldn't want to read an entire manual first.

Note that I've already searched the Codeigniter forums and found discussion on some of the required functionalities, however most of the interesting libraries seem to be available only on Codeigniter 1.7 and found little confirmation of those being available also for Codeigniter 2.1 ! Also, all Codeigniter books are for 1.7, and none for 2.1. Does that mean that 2.x doesn't have enough adoption and community support ?

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: @AymanSafadi, while I get the drift, IMHO the question asks pointedly about functionality supported by framework, and library availability of a specific later version of the framework. As you might note, I've already pretty much inclined towards Codeigniter (citing reasons), so that shouldn't evoke debate. Having said that, if you have suggestions on how to make the question more facts based, in acceptable QnA format, please do share.

Comment: not to give you a hard time, but I disagree. "pretty much inclined" still leaves room for debate. As for better questions, how about: 1) X was built for CI 1.7, how can I make it work for CI 2? 2) How do I make old CI plugins (or X plugin) work in CI 2? 3) What can I use to do X-functionality in CI?

Comment: Personally I'm a big fan of CodeIgniter. I'll do my best to answer your question.

Comment: Have take a look at [Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/)? I have similar case and phase with you, so I also haven't implemented / used it yet. But by skimming it's web doc's, this framework *seems* promising. Unfortunately it doesn't have good documentation as CI does yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. CodeIgniter 2 *is* a good choice.

1. It *is* pretty easy to use and learn. I'd suggest understanding the MVC architecture in general though. They're official documentation is awesome, although sometimes I yearn for the straight-forward API format. You'll notice that they don't show all the available parameters a function will accept up-front; sometimes you have to read the entire page to figure it out al your available options. Note: You'll find that there is no one way or standard in using models in CI. They're as helpful as you manually code them to be.
2. There are tons of libraries and helpers to do pretty much anything you need, as well as tutorials on how to do them. Not sure what you meant by *verification key sent via mobile phone*. AJAX is not a problem. CI has this pretty handy [`is_ajax_request()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) function that's really useful. Note: there used to be a problem with [AJAX request expiring sessions](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/102456/). Not sure if that's still an issue. As far as making it accessible for mobile-devices, you'll find more issues on the front-end than the back.
3. Baseline (virgin CI) performance is pretty good. It's up to you (your code and queries) to keep it lean.

Many of the libraries you find may *say* that they were made for 1.7, but may work with 2.x You can try updating them yourself if necessary. We'd be glad to help. Note that "plugins" have been deprecated in CI 2, you'll have to convert *plugins* to *helpers* or *libraries* (depending on your needs). CI 1.7 has a 3-year lead on CI 2. It'll take some time for "the community" to catch up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @AymanSafadi. Have spent some time yesterday reading about MVC architecture, and I think I get the hang of it, from an overall pattern standpoint. I guess it'll take a while to really settle-in, s.t. I can start seeing how I can compose a design around that. Regarding, "...verification key sent via mobile phone", is just a user-authentication mechanism, where user's identity and association with email-id is verified by asking them to click on a verification URL. Similar thing is done by Yahoo/Google when we associate mobile phone nos. with the account. Having a ready-to-use lib helps

Comment: , else I think this is still a manageable part, using bulk-SMS service sender API's. If there anything specific to comment on, regarding the quality of security (including usage of HTTPS URLs), of web-application created using CI ? Is CI better or worse compared to other frameworks in this regard ? Also, how secure can I expect my site to be against security attacks ? Does CI provide security as a feature, out-of-the-box, or needs heavy customization/extension for high grade of security, s.a. usage in enterprise environments ?

Comment: See what I mean by "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion"?

Comment: I can't answer all these questions; security is in the eye of the beholder. Security isn't a *thing* that's magically added to a PHP framework that comes in three different flavors, *low*, *medium*, and *high* grade security. CodeIgniter has a lot of security features, but so do others. If I say they're great, Zend fans will disagree. CI is just a piece of the puzzle; other security risks can be found in: SSL, JavaScript, database, the programmer's code, PHP itself, etc.